# Network request comes back after the controller is popped

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking, httprequest

I make a network request within a viewcontroller, the simplified code is as below:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self http_request];

}

- (void)http_request {

    dispatch_async(gAsynQueueT, ^{

        NSString *response;

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];

        ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];

        sleep(5); //leave some time for poping this controller

        [request startSynchronous];

        NSError *error = [request error];

        if (!error) {

           response = [request responseString];

        }

        dispatch_async(gMainQueueT, ^{

            _data = response;  //_data is an global variable

        });

    });


}
```

Before the network request coming back, I popped the controller. I think this should lead to memory leak, cause when the network request came back the controller is released. But I found nothing wrong with instrument tool.

So, how to expain this situation. Thanks~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already used dispatch_async(gAsynQueueT, {...}) and it will run on another thread.

And in block, you didn't use view controller's property so I think there is no reason for memory leak.

block was already dispatched to queue so it isn't related to view controller anyway.

Comment: In the MainQueue, I assign value to the property 'data' which belong to the view controller.

Comment: Ok then iOS will hold strong reference of view controller as you used them in your block, view controller object isn't destroyed when it is popped or dismissed,
Strictly in ARC memory management, an object is destroyed when its reference count becomes 0, so it is dismissed but never destroyed if you use data property of view controller and it will be destroyed after running that main queue code block, but you can't do any UI related action because it is already dismissed.

Comment: I understand. but, who holds the reference exactly, the queue?

Comment: Yes, so view controller reference is passed to  http_request -> gAsynQueueT -> gMainQueueT,   so that is the reason why blocks (ramda in other language) are powerful.

Comment: How about if I make the view controller as a delegate to respone the network request. As the same, I pop out the controller before the network comes back. does that cause some problems?

Comment: All delegates are declared as weak to prevent strong reference cycle issue in ARC,  so if you use view controller as weak delegate (weak reference) then view controller is popped and app would be crashed, but if you hold strong reference on delegate, it would not crash, also you can not do any UI actions on view controller and in that case pay attention to reference cycle issue.